# Progresso de upload com angular 6 e asp net core 2.2

Tags: angular-6, asp-net-core

Estou enviando um arquivo selecionado pelo usuário no navegador através da tag "input" para o asp net core e gostaria de exibir o progresso do envio.

Atualmente só recebo o resultado 2 do enum "HttpEventType" que significa "The response status code and headers were received". Não cai em nenhuma das duas condições esperadas neste código. Deveria receber callbacks com o resultado do tipo 1 "UploadProgress" para poder exibir o progresso na tela.

vide
[angular.io](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEventType)

```
    this.meuServico.saveFile(this.selectedFile).subscribe(
            (result) => {
                let event: any = result;

                if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                    // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
                    const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
                    console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
                }
                else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('upload error', error);
            }
        );
    }
```

meu serviço que cria o request:

```
public saveFile(file) {
    let url = 'minha url de backend asp net core 2.2 / uploadFile';

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);

    let headers = {};
    headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';

    let options: any = {
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events',
        headers: headers
    };

    return this.api.post(url, formData, options);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Só para atualizar vocês, meu problema era no backend. Na época a documentação não estava muito clara, poucos dias depois ela foi atualizada mas eu tinha esquecido de atualizar aqui.
A documentação na época não mostrava a definição da classe MultipartRequestHelper que foi um dos detalhes que faltavam.

[exemplo backend](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp)